# Como manter os botões do tipo submit com o mesmo aspecto do tipo button?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Precebi que quando coloco os botões num `form` eles ficam diferentes.

Isto foi o que eu fiz:

```php
<div class="btn-group" id="language_selector" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <?php                                               
        echo("<form action='' method='post'> 
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='en' value='EN' />
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='pt' value='PT' />
        <input type='submit'class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='es' value='ES'/>                            
</form>"); 
?>
```

Mas no aspecto é bastante diferente do exemplo:

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Gostaria que os botões do tipo *submit* ficassem iguais aos do tipo `button`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ecy7neto/3/

Comment: Tem algum exemplo no JSFiddle?

Comment: eu estava a usar este exemplo que é apresentado aqui http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: Qual a versão do bootstrap você está utilizando. Se você olhar [neste fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/ecy7neto/) você verá que o visual é o mesmo.

Comment: Editei https://jsfiddle.net/ecy7neto/3/ este é o aspecto

Comment: A única diferença que vejo é do seu `form`. Olhe [este exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/randrade/ecy7neto/10/) com as 4 possibilidades.

Comment: Alguma forma de manter o form e ter o mesmo formato nos botões?

Comment: O que é aquele `$activeClass`?

Comment: apenas uma variavel de controlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução e resolvi o problema com o seguinte código:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
 <div class="btn-group" id="language_selector" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <?php                                             
  echo("
     <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='en' value='EN' />
     <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='pt' value='PT' />
     <input type='submit'class='btn btn-default' $activeClass  name='es' value='ES'/>                           
       </div>
</form>"); 
    ?>
```

Se alguém tiver o mesmo problema que eu tive, esta é a solução: apenas alterei a ordem das tags, colocando o **form** por fora.